# When is it important to use the delete operator?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-leaks

So I know that memory management is important in c++, but usually, garbage collection gets neglected in my c++ programs.
I know there are some important cases where you want to use the delete operator so that you don't encounter a memory leak, but I'm not sure what they are.

Comment: What garbage collection?

Comment: Standard `c++` has no garbage collection. Remember the `c++` tag is for standard / unmanaged `c++` not .net / clr. If you are using .NET you may want to remove `c++` and add `c++-cli`

Comment: Never use `new`, and you won't need to use `delete`.  Instead use containers like `std::vector` and smart pointers like `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: Simplified rule: What you `new`, you must `delete`. What you `new[]`, you must `delete[]`. It's a lot of work, so start by using the containers in the standard library instead.

Comment: Modern `c++` encourages you to avoid the use of new. Instead use containers of the standard library and when you can't there are also smart pointers.

Comment: While manual usage of `new` and `delete` is not recommended, you could and might want to create overloaded `new` and `delete` operators for your class, which will be automatically called when you use smart pointers.

Answer (score 2):

When you use the `new` operator, memory is allocated on the heap. In order to free that memory, call `delete` on it. For example, for an int:

```
int * p_myint = new int;
delete p_myint;
```

Or for an object of a user-defined class:

```
MyClass * p_myobject = new MyClass;
delete p_myobject;
```

In general, each use of `new` requires a use of `delete`.

Note that to allocate memory for an array (and some related types), you use new[], and the allocated memory is similarly freed by delete[]. E.g.:

```
int * p_myints = new int[3];
delete[] p_myints;
```

Again, each use of `new[]` generally requires a use of `delete[]`.